# HTML and displaying of <img/> element

Tags: html, web-applications, jpeg, w3c

I am trying to understand whether or not the web allow for viewing of *progressive* JPEG or not.

Assume we have a server where (see [progressive jpegs](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2012/progressive-jpegs-a-new-best-practice/)):

```
$ identify /var/www/test.jpg
/var/www/test.jpg JPEG 2048x1080 2048x1080+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 129KB 0.020u 0:00.019
$ identify -verbose /var/www/test.jpg | grep Inter
  Interlace: JPEG
```

now if we place the following HTML document:

```
$ cat /var/www/test.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>jpg test</title></head>
<body>
<p><img src="test.jpg" width="256" height="128"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to understand whether or not (according to [img element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element)), a user agent is required to download the *whole* `2048x1080` image, while rendering region is only `256x128`.

Or on the contrary a *User Agent*, is allowed to take into account the rendering region: `256x128`, and therefore deduce it can only process a portion of the *progressive* JPEG. Knowing that there is no point in having the full resolution since it will not add any details to the image (well technically a quality layer should impact even at low resolution, this is just for simplification).

Typically, I'd like to know within an application such as google maps, if a *User Agent* can abort (suspend?) retrieval of currently displayed images, since User decide to zoom in some more based only on partial result from decompressing a *progressive* JPEG (the whole JPEG is not yet on User side).

---

Update: It turns out that web is trying a different approach here with the `loading` attribute in HTML:

```
<img src="example.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="example" />
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you're asking if the web browser is allowed to abort the render/download for a high resolution image prematurely when it has enough of a progressive JPEG to display the image at the resolution its <img>-tag specify?

Comment: Correct. Or more generally "When is the web browser allowed to abort the download of an img src ?"

Comment: I doubt any current browser will abort the download when it has enough resolution, but your question is a good incentive for browser developers. Maybe someone first implements what your question suggests, and then gives you the answer for that particular browser :-) Consider also that not downloading the full image may have downsides, because you may lose a preload that could have been intended as an optimization.

Comment: now that I think of it, if I were a supergood browser developer with a lot of time, I think I would **suspend** the download when resolution is sufficient, not abort it

Comment: ... and resume it when there is enough bandwidth again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just discovered related proposals at:

- http://opensores.za.net/2012/responsive-images/
- http://blog.yoav.ws/2012/05/Responsive-image-format
- http://timkadlec.com/2013/06/why-we-need-responsive-images/
- http://24ways.org/2012/responsive-images-what-we-thought-we-needed/

and a framework:

- https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-image-optimize#JpegRecompressionQualityForSmallScreens

Answer (score 7):

The idea of using a progressive JPEG in a website has less to do with saving bandwidth and more to do with showing something to the end user earlier.  The browser still downloads the full image no matter what, but progressive JPEGs allow the user to see something happening earlier.

The [W3 page](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/) on JPEG says this:

> Progressive JPEG is a means of reordering the information so that, after only a small part has been downloaded, a hazy view of the entire image is presented rather than a crisp view of just a small part.

Because the inclusion of an IMG tag generally means that you want the browser to download that asset, it's not going to abort it partway through simply because it's determined it's downloaded "enough".  The browser also doesn't know what you intend to do with the image later - maybe you'll zoom it later on, or maybe it'll need to show it later at a different size.  Partially downloading once means that the browser might have to download again later.

And the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) on JPEG points out:

> However, progressive JPEGs are not as widely supported,[citation needed] and even some software which does support them (such as versions of Internet Explorer before Windows 7)[12] only displays the image after it has been completely downloaded.

So even if some browsers did abort connections for these after having downloaded "enough", not enough browsers provide support for me to consider even using them in the first place.

Comment: My question was about what the standard allows, not about which particular implementation is broken...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is there is no standard way to abort an `img` (progressive or otherwise) without leaving or aborting the page or changing the src of the tag (and this will remove the partial image). I don't know of any hacks that will do it either.

While this sounds like a nice feature it would be problematic for existing websites in the following common cases:

- An image gallery using large progressive images as thumbnails + preload (ie, [Galleria](http://galleria.io/) does this)
- ANY website that relies on `onload` events for the image (at what point would your half-rendered image be considered "loaded" if it can abort/suspend)?

For these reasons alone it would be a bad idea unless added to the spec as an attribute (like the deprecated `lowsrc` attribute or maybe some kind of `allowpartial` attribute where you are explicitly asking for this behaviour). As somebody who has followed the WHATWG discussions I can tell you it would almost certainly be rejected outright for the simple reason that it adds complexity to solve a fringe issue. If this feature was really required there would have been demands for it years ago before broadband became almost universal. At this point in the game it's essentially redundant with clever use of Javascript and/or thumbnails.

Comment: the fact that people add complexity by using thumbnails, clearly indicates that something is missing. you're saying that the standard is written this way: so as you prevent people from using progressive JPEG, JPEG-XR and/or JPEG 2000, right ?

Comment: I'm not saying the standard prevents you from using progressive images, I'm saying it doesn't allow the renderer to just stop downloading an image based on some arbitrary visual decision about what is "enough". If you ask for it you'll probably have to provide a more convincing use case. Your question was "when is the browser allowed to stop downloading an image?", the answer is "When you leave/abort the page". The rest of you question is basically a proposal that I highly doubt will ever be accepted as you've put it.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand your question, the answer will largely be dependent on the browsers you want to support.

Browser behavior can be easily checked with 3rd party plugins like "Firebug". these plugins can show you the progress of a page's creation, what is being requested and how many bytes are being sent to and from a server. In Firebug it can be seen in the "Net" tab.

Comment: No, my question is not about *a* specific implementation, but instead what the standard mandates/recommends/allows.